# Benefits of making custom domain as "Primary"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We added & verified custom domain in the Azure tenant and with that we can sync on-premises accounts with (xyz.com) prefix. However, I have not made custom domain as "Primary".

I would like to know the impact of not making it primary or the benefits to do it. For now, (abc.onmicrosoft.com) is a primary for us and we have no issues.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The impact**

The primary domain is the default domain name for a new user when you create a new user.

If your primary domain is xx.onmicrosoft.com, the new user should be username@xx.onmicrosoft.com.

If your primary domain is xx.com, the new user should be username@xx.com.

[image]

**The benifit**

Setting a primary domain name streamlines the process for an administrator to create new users in the portal.

Comment: Thank you Tony. It makes sense, when we create "Cloud Only" user account's, because the users i am creating via AAD Connect are having @xx.com domain name without making xx.com as Primary. Correct?